# no puedo pasar las querys a promesas en typescript

Tags: mysql, nodejs, typescript

Tengo un problema, estoy migrando un proyecto de node a typescript ya que me parece bueno, lo malo, es que en la conexión a la base de datos lo que yo hacía era convertir los callbacks de `connection.query` en promesas, de la siguiente manera:

```
connection.query = promisify(connection.query);
```

Pero resulta que al hacerlo con typescript me sale el siguiente error:

```
El tipo '(arg1: string | QueryOptions) => Promise<unknown>' no se puede asignar al tipo 'QueryFunction'.
  Al tipo "Promise<unknown>" le faltan las propiedades siguientes del tipo "Query": sql, nestedTables, start, determinePacket y 8 más.
```

Ahora, supongo yo que lo que pasa es que como en typescript no se pueden cambiar así como así las variables de callbacks a promesas, por eso me da error, lo malo es que no sé que hacer para que funcione, porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar.

Anexo codigo de mi arhcivo de conexión a la DB(osea el del problema):

```
import {createPool, PoolConnection} from 'mysql';
import {promisify} from 'util';
const {database} = require('./config');

function connect(): Promise<PoolConnection> {
  return new Promise((resolved, reject) => {
    const pool = createPool(database);
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      if (connection) {
        connection.query = promisify(connection.query);
        resolved(connection);
      }
    });
  });
}

module.exports = connect;
```

De antemano muchas gracias al alma caritativa que me dé la solución.

Comment: has probado que pasa si a tu parámetro connection le dices que sea de tipo any, es decir tienes pool.getConnection((err, connection), modificalo de la siguiente manera → pool.getConnection((err, connection: any). Prueba y me comentas

Comment: @jorgeGomez, que crack mi amigo, me ha funcionado, no me la esperaba, ya al ponerle el any no me salta el error, muchisimas gracias mi amigo !

Comment: vale, con gusto, realmente es un problema de tipado lo que presentabas. el any, lo que hace es decir que ese parámetro va a recibir cualquier tipo.